# C# - Finding the right Port to read data

Tags: c#, usb, ports

I got a old USB device which sends data to the USB buffer, I want to Code a program which reads through all connected devices and reads the right buffer.

I got the USB ID from a example program: Device ID: `USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\5&1BD05EBE&0&2`

But how can I now use this Information to specify the the right port?

All I got until now is this example program and I just don't understand how I should achieve that. (It is my first time playing with usb ports)

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();

      foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Device ID: {0}, PNP Device ID: {1}, Description: {2}",
            usbDevice.DeviceID, usbDevice.PnpDeviceID, usbDevice.Description);
      }

      Console.Read();
    }

    static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
    {
      List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

      ManagementObjectCollection collection;
      using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub")) collection = searcher.Get();      

      foreach (var device in collection)
      {
        devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
        (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
        (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
        (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
        ));
      }

      collection.Dispose();
      return devices;
    }
  }

  class USBDeviceInfo
  {
    public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description)
    {
      this.DeviceID = deviceID;
      this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
      this.Description = description;
    }
    public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
  }

}
```

Any help is appreachiated!
Kind regards,
Raavgo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267538/access-usb-port-from-c-sharp-and-send-and-receive-data

Comment: That appears to be the VID & PID for a FTDI FT232R USB-Serial Port converter. This link may give an idea of how to match the Device ID string to the corresponding serial port : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32330/A-Useful-WMI-Tool-How-To-Find-USB-to-Serial-Adapto